# Cabal on windows (from chocolatey) doesn't build projects with libraries

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am having issues building a project with a library using cabal installed with haskell-dev using chocolatey on windows (i.e. the recommended approach, everyting out of the box). I initially thought the issue was related to my specific project but it's actually easily reproduced by just creating a template project with

```
cabal init --libandexe
cabal configure
```

And then `cabal build` fails to build with the following errors:

```
cabal.exe: Failed to build testcabal1-0.1.0.0 (which is required by
exe:testcabal1 from testcabal1-0.1.0.0). The failure occurred during the final
install step. The exception was:
dieVerbatim: user error (cabal.exe:
'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\ghc\tools\ghc-8.10.2\bin\ghc-pkg.exe' exited
with an error:
testcabal1-0.1.0.0: Warning: library-dirs: C:\Program doesn't exist or isn't a
directory
testcabal1-0.1.0.0: Warning: dynamic-library-dirs: C:\Program doesn't exist or
isn't a directory
testcabal1-0.1.0.0: Warning: haddock-interfaces:
C:\projects\haskell\testcabal1\dist-newstyle\build\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.10.2\testcabal1-0.1.0.0\doc\html\testcabal1\testcabal1.haddock
doesn't exist or isn't a file
testcabal1-0.1.0.0: Warning: haddock-html:
C:\projects\haskell\testcabal1\dist-newstyle\build\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.10.2\testcabal1-0.1.0.0\doc\html\testcabal1
doesn't exist or isn't a directory
testcabal1-0.1.0.0: library-dirs: Files\Haskell is a relative path which makes
no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative to). You can make paths
relative to the package database itself by using ${pkgroot}. (use --force to
override)
testcabal1-0.1.0.0: library-dirs: Platform\8.6.5\mingw\lib is a relative path
which makes no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative to). You can
make paths relative to the package database itself by using ${pkgroot}. (use
--force to override)
testcabal1-0.1.0.0: dynamic-library-dirs: Files\Haskell is a relative path
which makes no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative to). You can
make paths relative to the package database itself by using ${pkgroot}. (use
--force to override)
testcabal1-0.1.0.0: dynamic-library-dirs: Platform\8.6.5\mingw\lib is a
relative path which makes no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative
to). You can make paths relative to the package database itself by using
${pkgroot}. (use --force to override)
)
```

It seems to have something to do with spaces in some directory names where cabal / ghc were installed by chocolatey? Any ideas?

Comment: ok is turned out it was picking up some remains of pre-chocolatey GHC installation (ie haskell platform, that lived somewhere in c:\program files\...). Had to (not sure if it all was necessary):
a) uninstall everything haskell-related from chocolatey
b) removed everything to do with cabal from c:\users\<user>
c) installed haskell-dev back using chocolatey
d) profit!

Comment: you should post the fix as an answer so the question does not appear unanswered.